# How to change initial position of drag-down scroll in web Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

Normally web page automatically scroll down or scroll up when mouse with link or drag element reach bottom/top of the view port.I need to change the position of start scrolling of the webpage, the web page or particular `<div>` scroll down/up when a drag-element reach some distance of the view port.How can achieve this. I am using angular-drag-and-drop-lists Plug.

**Default Scrolling Start Position:**

[image]

**Customize Scroll start Position (I need this result):**
[image]

Comment: please could you add some code.. A snippet or a jsfiddle... your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: normally web page is automatically scroll when mouse (with darg element) reach bottom of the view port. So i need, page start automatic scrolling some distance above from the view port.

Comment: adding a comment is not helpful. Add some code to demonstrate how far you've progressed, what you've tried etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need some js code based on [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) event.

Quick html example:

```
<a href="" ondrag="calcCoords(event)">Example link</a>

<script>
//Put distance you want to scroll from
var youMaxDist = 50;
var scrollSpeed = 10;

function calcCoords(event) {

   //Distance to buttom. It isn't works fine, but good enough
   var currDist = window.innerHeight - event.clientY;

   //Trigger scroll
   if(currDist < youMaxDist)
     window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollTop + scrollSpeed);
}
</script>
```

Also, please, pay some attention for browser version supports and mobile screen issues

Comment: Thanks a lot. your answer give a idea to achieve my problem